# Sort records but keeping header at the top in Linux and Java

Tags: java, linux, shell, sorting, unix

I need to sort records from a file by first column numerically but I need the header to stay at the top of the file. 
I am using Java's Process Builder but I am not familiar with Linux commands so I am doing something wrong. This is what I need help with:

```
Process sort = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "((head -n -1 "     +main_file+ " | tail -n -1) | sort -n) >> " + main_file).start();
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're processing the file from the Linux command line rather than parsing the file from Java?

Comment: yes, my professor asked me to use Linux commands @BJBlack

Comment: Hint: a good start would be leave the java part out of the picture. You should focus on getting a sequence of linux shell commands going; and then you push that into a process buider call. And just for the record, if that is the only thing your java code is doing, it sounds like a pointless assignment to run that from Java.

Comment: thats not the only thing my java program is doing. It's only a tiny part of it that I am really struggling with :) @GhostCat

Answer (score 5):

You dont need java to execute a shell and perform the task, directly run the commands on shell .

See below

```
$ cat delitLater.txt
A 1
B 2
C 3
A 4
B 5
C 6
$ awk 'NR==1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -n -k 1,1"}' delitLater.txt
A 1
A 4
B 2
B 5
C 3
C 6
$ awk 'NR==1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -n -k 2,2"}' delitLater.txt
A 1
B 2
C 3
A 4
B 5
C 6
```

Using awk , you print the first line as is. This is done using NR(Rownumber) == 1 . For all other rows , you use the sort command and specify which columns to use . Sort key is defined by "-k" option . "-n" means numeric sort , but you might or might not need it depending upon the contents of your file.

Comment: Can you please explain it to me a little bit? Which command should I write in the process builder? @am1704

Comment: Updated my answer with reasoning , let me know if you want me to elaborate. Requires understanding of awk syntax and sort command options - you can lookup the man pages for both the commands .